# MySQL/python charset issues

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I am using pymysql (0.9.3) to join and clean MySQL server (8.0.19) tables through python and writing the table onto the database using sqlalchemy. But keep producing an incorrect string value error.

`InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x81asis...' for column 'client_last_name' at row 726")`

I have tried using latin1, utf8 and utf8mb4 charsets in my database connection and engine creator but the error is the same.

```
db = pymysql.connect(host='', 
                          user='', 
                          password='', 
                          db='',
                          charset="utf8mb4")

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@port/schema'+'?charset=utf8mb4')

con = engine.connect()
```

This is the code line generating the failure:
`full_email_stats.to_sql("email_stats", con, if_exists="replace")`

The traceback is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-33-8abe82be8923>", line 128, in <module>
    full_email_stats.to_sql("email_stats", con, if_exists="replace")

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2663, in to_sql
    method=method,

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 521, in to_sql
    method=method,

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1317, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 755, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 669, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1226, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 148, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 197, in executemany
    self._get_db().encoding)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 229, in _do_execute_many
    rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

  File "/Users/AdrianAlvarez/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x81asis...' for column 'client_last_name' at row 726")
```

The data frames had a different charset in MySQL. Anyone got an idea on how to tackle this?

This might be a stretch, but I did the same procedure in r and had no issues with charsets. Does anyone know why?

Comment: start with which code line is generating the failure? What is the full backtrace? Which PyMYSQL version? Does a later version fix it? Which mysql server version?

Comment: I can't see any [similar error since that release](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed). Please double check or install PyMySQL from github master in a virtual env.  If this still occurs, raise an upstream bug. Try to minimize the example to a PyMySQL only example by extracting what the sqlachemy generated query. Be very clear in your upstream bug. The maintainer isn't a native english speaker. Be simple, clear, and complete (include sample code, backtrace, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and server version).

Comment: I actually messed up the MySQL server version is:  5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: If that doesn't help at all i'll raise the upstream bug.

Comment: PyMySQL shouldn't backtrace on a supported version on MySQL, with 5.7.{very latest} definitely is.

Comment: Thanks danblack! I raised the issue in github

Comment: Apologies. looking back at the github issue you raised, '\\xC5\\x81asis.' doesn't map to the charset of lastname. `SHOW CREATE TABLE email_stats` shows the schema for the table. So its MySQL giving an error about your data for lastname.

Comment: Got you, any ideas? Ive been battling with this for a while. I don't know why but doing the same thing in r was extremely easy.

Comment: Hex `C581` is `Ł` (Stroke L) in utf8 and utf8mb4.  That has been the case since MySQL 4.1.  The doubled-up backslashes worry me.  Do you see that in other charset issues with Python?  Do you have this at the start of source files?  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.  More notes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python